# httpclient, DefaultHttpClient, HttpPost ,BasicNameValuePair,NameValuePair are deprecated

Tags: java, android

I'm new in android app. The main point i want to send data from android app to php page but i get the following errors in my codes

org.apache.http.impl.client.defaulthttpclient is deprecated.

I had try  a lot of way but not yet successed.

my android is `1.2.1.1 (API 22: 5.1.1)`.

below is my code.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dataOne", "Hello"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dataTwo", "Android World"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can:

- Switch to using [Apache's HttpClient standalone library](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html), or
- Switch to using Java's standard `HttpUrlConnection`, or
- Switch to an independent HTTP access library, like [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/), or
- Continue using the deprecated classes and methods, bearing in mind that doing so will become increasingly difficult with time

Comment: Thank you for your help but as i told i am new in android so i do not know how  Switch to using Apache's HttpClient standalone library, Switch to using Java's standard HttpUrlConnection and Switch to an independent HTTP access library. Please tell me what i doing to switch?

Comment: @MakameSharif: Then you are going to need to learn, just as you need to learn how to build Android apps. `HttpUrlConnection` has been around for close to 20 years. There are many books, blog posts, and online tutorials on Java programming that will cover `HttpUrlConnection`. With respect to the other options, you can start by clicking on the links in my answer, which lead to Web pages that discuss those libraries.

Comment: thank you for your intention of help me, i know what do you mean. thank for that but let me ask another question. I want to write data to text file but i do know where to create my text file.